# Docker run failed when creating container with spring-boot:build-image in java 8

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit https://start.spring.io/
2. Select Java 8 on the list of options
3. Click generate to download the project.
4. Open the application and run it locally (perhaps in your favorite IDE). It should be good.
5. Build docker image > `mvn spring-boot:build-image`
6. Run docker image: > `docker run -p 8080:8080 demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

**Expected**: I would expect the application to come up and be accessible.

**Actual**: I get the following error

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fca96e932f7, pid=1, tid=0x00007fca97ffb700
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_302-b08) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.302-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xb2a2f7]  VirtualMemoryTracker::add_reserved_region(unsigned char*, unsigned long, NativeCallStack const&, MemoryType, bool)+0x77
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /workspace/hs_err_pid1.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bell-sw.com/support
#
```

The same default project when using Java 11 runs fine.
This issue started happening about 4 days ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs due to the issue: [After BuildPack 8.7.0, JVM Launch Error in JRE 8 #131](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/issues/131).

There is a workaround as Daniel Mikusa said in the [comment](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/issues/131#issuecomment-927171992):

> You can work around this for now by adding BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED=false when you run your application image. This will disable Java NMT. You must do this at runtime, not build time. So if you are running your container images with Docker, then you'd use docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED=false apps/maven.

For instance:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED=false my_app:testing
```